# How to avoid the forge model derivative queue

Tags: forge

I want to use the forge viewer as a preview tool in my web app for generated data.
The problem I have is that the model derivative API is sometimes slow sometimes fast.
I read that this happens because the files are placed in a queue and being processed subsequentially.

In my opinion, this can be solved by:

1. Having the extraction.update webhook also tell me where I am in the queue. So I can inform my users with better progress information. Or when the queue is too long I can not stop the process.
2. Being able to have a private queue. I have no problem paying more credits if necessary.
3. Being able to generate svf2 files on my own server.

But I don't know if any of these options are possible. Or if there is another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, that could be useful. I logged that request in our system: **DERI-7940**
2. Might be considered later on, but no plans currently
3. I'm not aware of any plans for that

We're always working on making the translation service better, but unfortunately, I cannot tell when it will meet your requirements - including the implementation of the webhook feature you mentioned.

**SVF2** is specifically for very large models - is that what you are working with? If not, then I'm quite certain that translating to **SVF** would be faster.